# sql server table data in Flash dynamic textbox using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, sql-server-2005

i have dynamic text-fields in flash (AS 3) and button on my form. my backend is sql server and i want show data in text-fields on button click event. i m using asp.net as server side script.

I have Form in Flash and i want to fetch data in form on flash button click event from sql server .

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

**It will help you..**

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("your aspx page url");

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);


btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_submit_click);
function btn_submit_click(e:Event)
{

        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
}

function urlLoader_complete(e:Event)
{
        txt_box.text = e.target.data.aspx_var;
}
```

you need to just print varible in your aspx page. like in PHP i am writing this(bcause i don't know aspx).

```
<?
   echo "aspx_var=value";
?>
```